# AVplayer with authenticated URL

Tags: swiftui

How do I handle Video URLs with token to stream via AV Player ?
Example URL : http://example.com/video.mp4?token=authtoken

Chrome handles and plays the video.
But when I use this url in AV Player, it doesn't do anything.

please help me sort this out.

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/video/X-ABC- The Super Hero (2000).mp4?token=_CTV24K7jFmNnH2TFH4Ehw&a=1708455493".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        
        let url = URL(string: urlString!)
        //url = http://example.com/video/X-ABC-%20The%20Super%20Hero%20(2000).mp4?token=_CTV24K7jFmNnH2TFH4Ehw&a=1708455493
        
        
        Text(url!.absoluteString)
        
        VideoPlayer(url: url!, play: $play, time: $time)
                    .mute(mute)
                    .onBufferChanged { progress in
                        // Network loading buffer progress changed
                        print(progress)
                    }
                    .onPlayToEndTime {
                        // Play to the end time.
                    }
                    .onReplay {
                        // Replay after playing to the end.
                    }
                    .onStateChanged { state in
                        switch state {
                        case .loading:
                            print(url!.absoluteString)
                            print(state)
                        case .playing(let totalDuration):
                            print(state)
                        case .paused(let playProgress, let bufferProgress):
                            print(state)
                        case .error(let error):
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
```

tried using different libraries and solutions on different forum but nothing worked.

```
Error : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media may be damaged., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c8e430 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12848 "(null)"}}
```

Comment: `AVPlayer` and Chrome are comparable?  One is a Swift class, the other a web browser.

Comment: Start with `curl`, using the encoded version of the URL. Make sure you can download this file using this URL from the command-line, and that the website is not doing something Chrome-specific. As a rule, I would avoid testing things with Chrome unless your goal is specifically to support Chrome. It is extremely magical.

Comment: Given the "may be damaged" (rather than some other error), I highly expect they're playing some game with JavaScript here and not returning you the mp4 directly.

Answer (score 0):

The trick might be that you need to use percent encoding  `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)`

```
guard let urlString = "http://example.com/video.mp4?token=authtoken".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
      let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    print("Invalid URL")
    return
}

let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

On the other hand, if you use a more sophisticated authentication mechanism with an HTTP header token, you can try `AVURLAsset`:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/video.mp4") else {
    print("Invalid URL")
    return
}

let options: [String: Any] = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": ["Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"]]

let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: options)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Comment: Getting Error : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media may be damaged. But it works fine when used directly in Chrme